# Postman still sends to old sever although I updated its' variable

Tags: api, caching, request, postman

Postman still sends to old sever although I updated its' variable. It works correctly on the web app. I've changed the server & linked the new server with the same sub-domain and deployed the same old app.

**The windows app**

[image]

**The web app - works fine and it responds as it should**

[image]

1. I changed the variable of the URL [image]
2. I tried to create a new environment - didn't work
3. I tried to remove the entire workspace - didn't work
4. I un/re-installed the app - didn't work either

**Is there a cache in the app itself or something to clear it to get the new value?**

appreciate your help. T^T

An example to clarify my issue:

- I have a subdomain: backend.mydomain.com
- I've linked my server IP 152.50.133.60
- so backend.mydomain.com points to -> 152.50.133.60
- I made backend.mydomain.com free again to use it on a different server
- Now I linked my new server IP 163.33.80.92
- Now my backend.mydomain.com points to -> 163.33.80.92 & it works fine on (the postman web app & chrome)
- When I try from PC app it still has the old value as in console pic

Comment: Did you check collection variable or global variable?

Comment: In collection variable isn't needed to be updated since I registered it with the same example.com.
the global variable is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked after:

1. Signed Out.
2. Made a request not signed in.
3. Signed in again, then made a request it worked.

No clue why though!